# Getting phpunit-exported selenium IDE files to run in WebDriver

Tags: php, selenium, ide

I have created a number of selenium IDE files that I converted to phpunit format in Firefox IDE 2.9.1.1 (on a Windows box), using Options -> Format converter. Those converted files define a class "Example" that is derived from class PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase. I now know that this class needs to be changed to PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase. The problem is, I cannot get this to run with recent versions of phpunit.

I am running these tests on a Fedora 24 VM which is using php 5.6.30, java 1.8.0_121-b14, and firefox 51.0.1-2. I have tried to get these to run using selenium standalone server 3.0.1 (and now 3.1.0), and phpunit 5.7.13. I have the latest php facebook WebDriver installed. The error I keep getting is that the above mentioned class is not found.  I did a grep on that class and this is what I found:

> [root@localhost bin]# grep -r "PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase" .
>
> Binary file ./phpunit/phpunit-4.6.7.phar matches
>
> Binary file ./phpunit/phpunit-4.7.6.phar matches

So, it appears that this class does not exist in phpunit 5.7 and above (which are in that directory), nor does it exist in html-runner.phar, which is in the same directory. The seleniumhq.org site says to use html runner if you convert from IDE, but I can find no examples of how to use the html-runner.phar file (and no documentation).

Can someone please tell me what I should change the class name to, to get this test to work?

UPDATE:

I now know that if I want to use phpunit and selenium server to drive a firefox browser, I have to get selenium talking to geckodriver. I have installed:

> geckodriver 0.14.0 at /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
>
> selenium server 3.0.1 at /usr/local/bin/selenium
>
> phpunit-5.7.13.phar installed at /usr/local/bin/phpunit
>
> I used composer to add webdrivers (facebook 1.3.0 :
>
> [root@localhost composer]# cat composer.json
>   {
>       "require": {
>           "facebook/webdriver": "^1.3",
>           "phpunit/phpunit": ">=3.7",
>           "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2"
>       }
>   }
>
> php composer.phar install

They were added to the PATH:

> [bjt@localhost projects]$ echo $PATH
>   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin/selenium:/usr/local/bin/phpunit:/usr/local/bin/composer:/usr/local/bin/geckodriver

I have a small test file:

> ?php
>
> require_once('/usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/autoload.php');
>
> class test extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
>
> {
>
> protected function setUp()
>
> {
>
> ```
> $this->setBrowser("*firefox");
>
> $this->setBrowserUrl("https://fakeurl.com/");
> ```
>
> }
>
> public function testMyTestCase()
>
> {
>
> ```
> $this->open("/");
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Starting the selenium server:

> java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium/selenium-standalone-3.0.1.jar

When I run the test:

> /usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit-5.7.13.phar --verbose test.php

Yields this error:

> PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: The best matching driver provider Firefox/Marionette driver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{browserName=*firefox}]

So, it appears that geckodriver is not talking to selenium server. If I try to force the issue by changing the execution of the server:

> java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver/geckodriver" -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar

or

> sudo java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver/geckodriver" -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar

It makes no difference. I'm hoping someone can point out what I am missing. I'm at a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working through the same process of getting this to work and would like to point out a few things:

- htmlrunner is meant to run the test cases saved directly from the Selenium IDE in the default format, which is html.
- Make sure you can run firefox from the terminal running the selenium server.
- You added two different selenium php bindings.  The facebook one and the phpunit-selenium.  I currently have it working with only the facebook binding and phpunit extending the class PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.  I would recommend using the example provided within github for facebook/webdriver without phpunit to verify that your selenium config is working, then add phpunit.

Comment: I have started using htmlrunner. No success so far. Firefox does run within the terminal window. And I cannot get the github example to work. I get an error: "Error: Class 'WebDriverCapabilityType' not found. I see in the comments that others have the same issue, but their solutions don't work for me.